# Error in make post reques using RETROFIT

Tags: android

I have a problem in using retrofit. I have a API `https://raakar.ir/addProject` and want to send some information. API works fine in postman. I want to make post request. I think, I do every think correctly. But when I run the app, It crash. 
I used these libraries:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

and these are my interface of retrofit :

```
public interface APIInterface {

@Multipart
@POST("addProject")
Call<AddProjectResponse> post(
        @Header("token") String token,
        @Field("name") String name,
        @Field("amount") String amount,
        @Field("description") String description,
        @Field("category") String category,
        @Field("deadline") String deadline,
        @Field("projectFile")Bitmap bitmap
        );
}
```

*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

```
Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://raakar.ir/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    APIinterface retroInterface = retrofit.create(APIinterface.class);

    Call<AddProjectResponse> call = retroInterface.post(token,
            "طراحی راکار",
            "50000000",
            "خالی است",
            "برنامه نویسی",
            "5",
            null);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<AddProjectResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AddProjectResponse> call, Response<AddProjectResponse> response) {
            Log.d("Resposne:", response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AddProjectResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Respone:", "Error");
        }
    });
```

**PLEASE** HELP me!

Comment: Please share crash log

Comment: it doesn't show any blue log in logcat

Answer (score 0):

i thing if you are not post any image and other file like video etc then you can not used @Multipart and also pass in post method paremater make one pojo class for that and only pass your object like below that...sample code

```
       MyEventRequestModel myEventListRequestModel = new MyEventRequestModel(); // define your pojo class object 
    myEventListRequestModel.setDate(mDate);
    Call<MyEventResponseModel> call = apiInterface.getAllEvent(myEventListRequestModel);
```

and header will be set on retrofit intialized..

```
OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            if (context == null) {
                request = request
                        .newBuilder()
                        .build();
            } else {
                request = request
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AppSetting.getStringSharedPref(context, Constants.USER_KEY_TOKEN, "")) // hear define your header.
                        .build();
            }
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If You use  @Multipart than use  @Part not @Field

```
  public interface APIInterface {
  @Multipart
  @POST("addProject")
      Call<AddProjectResponse> post(
      @Part ("token") String token,
      @Part ("name") String name,
      @Part ("amount") String amount,
      @Part ("description") String description,
      @Part ("category") String category,
      @Part ("deadline") String deadline,
      @Part MultipartBody.Part img
    );
}
```

Comment: I change it but that crash again :(

Comment: @hosein This is correct Formate for  multipart upload you may worng on image upload  see example http://www.pratikbutani.com/2016/06/android-upload-image-file-using-retrofit-2-0/.

Comment: I copied correct code from another project but it crash